# Add proxyAddresses to Active Directory users when created in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I am trying to add users in Active Directory. Those users need to have proxyAddresses. My problem is that those proxyAddresses are multiples and stored in an array.

I try :

```
$proxyAddresses = @("address1@test.com", "address2@test.com", "address3@test.com")
$userInstance = new-object Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADUser
$userInstance.ProxyAddresses = $proxyAddresses
New-ADUser test -Instance $userInstance
```

And I get this error :

```
 Invalid type 'System.Management.Automation.PSObject'. Parameter name: proxyAddresses
```

I would like to add this proxyAddresses array to the attribute proxyAddresses of my AD user but it don't seem to be possible.

Any idea how this could be done?

Comment: Convert that `$proxyAddresses` to `[String[]]`?

Comment: I tried to "join" the $proxyAddresses array, the problem is that what is stored in AD is one string "address1@test.com;address2@test.com;address3@test.com" and not 3 different strings.

Comment: Try direct typecast at assignment: `$userInstance.ProxyAddresses = [Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADPropertyValueCollection]$proxyAddresses`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Anything wrong with using [`Set-ADUser`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee617215.aspx)?

```
$username = '...'
$proxyAddresses = 'address1@example.com', 'address2@example.com', 'address3@example.com'

New-ADUser -Name $username
Set-ADUser -Identity $username -Add @{
  'proxyAddresses' = $proxyAddresses | % { "smtp:$_" }
}
```

Comment: I didn't think it could work when I posted the question, but it did! Thank you very much.

Comment: I made a function Get-ProxyAddresses for me. It gets the various combinations of usernames and domains and makes a list of them. https://gist.github.com/PsychoData/dd475c27f7db5ce982cd6160c74ee1d0

Comment: for example Get-ProxyAddress -username 'john.smith', 'james.smith' -domains 'domain.com','domain.net'
SMTP:john.smith@domain.com
smtp:john.smith@domain.net
smtp:james.smith@domain.com
smtp:james.smith@domain.net

Answer (score 0):

I just had this same issue and I was pretty sure I was passing in a string array (that's how it was declared).

Problem was just before I sent my string array into AD I was passing it to "Sort-Object -Unique" - which unbeknownst to me was changing either the type or something that made the cmdlet unhappy.

Just FYI...Sort-Object can burn you in these circumstances.

Answer (score 0):

So, in my testing of this. I made Get-ProxyAddresses at https://gist.github.com/PsychoData/dd475c27f7db5ce982cd6160c74ee1d0

```
function Get-ProxyAddresses
{
    Param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)] 
    [string[]]$username,
    [string[]]$domains = 'domain.com'
    )

    #Strip off any leading @ signs people may have provided. We'll add these later 
    $domains = $domains.Replace('@','')

    $ProxyAddresses = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList
    foreach ($uname  in $username) {
        foreach ($domain in $domains ) {
            if ($ProxyAddresses.Count -lt 1) {
                $ProxyAddresses.Add( "SMTP:$uname@$domain" ) | Out-Null
            } else {
                $ProxyAddresses.Add( "smtp:$uname@$domain" ) | Out-Null
            }
        }
    }
    return $ProxyAddresses 
}
```

It just returns as a collection. Pretty kludgy, but works for what I need. It also assumes the first username and first domain are the "primary"

I combined that with @ansgar's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31136898/2238544) and tried just `-OtherAttributes` on New-Aduser

```
$proxyAddresses = Get-ProxyAddress -username 'john.smith', 'james.smith' -domains 'domain.com','domain.net'

New-ADUser      -Name $username 
                -OtherAttributes @{       
                    'proxyAddresses'= $proxyAddresses
                }
```

Works perfectly and added the proxyAddresses for me right at creation, without having to have a separate set action afterwards.

If you are Going to do separate actions, I would recommend to use `-Server`, like below, so that you don't run into talking to two different DCs by accident (and you also know that the New-ADUser is finished and already there, you don't have to wait for replication)

```
#I like making it all in one command, above, but this should work fine too. 
$ADServer = (Get-ADDomainController).name
New-ADUser -Server $ADServer -name $Username
Set-ADUSer -Server $ADServer -Identity $username -Add @{
  'proxyAddresses' = $proxyAddresses | % { "smtp:$_" }
}
```